# How do I building disque with make? Missing jemalloc/jemalloc.h error

Tags: message-queue, disque

When building disque with make getting the following error:

> Missing jemalloc/jemalloc.h

Comment: Thanks that worked. Also had to `apt-get install tk8.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
$ make distclean
$ make
```